# Make Datatables row clickable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table which is loaded with data via ajax using datatables.net.  I'd like to make it so that when the user clicks on a row it links to a URL appended with the get variable of that row's primary key.

I'm rather new to Datatables so my hacked attempt/idea was to use Datatables to apply two classes two the column with my primary key.  The two classes were hide (css of display:none) and projectID (identifying that column so I can grab it's value with jquery).  I was able to apply those classes using the aoColumns property and it did hide the column and append the projectID class as well.  However I think since Datatables is creating the table it's preventing me from using

```
$('#project-table tr').click(function(){alert('clicked');}
```

so I tried

```
$('#project-table tr').live('click',function(){alert('clicked');})};
```

Also to no avail.

I would imagine there is a better way than I'm using to make a row clickable, linking to a page with appended primary key get variable, but I couldn't find an example.  If anyone has a link to an example or could point me in the right direction it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I have a table which is loaded with data via ajax using datatables.net**

That means that any event handlers bound to the elements during page load will not be applicable to the loaded data unless the event is delegated to a static parent element -- meaning that the element is never removed or replaced, and will exist indefinitely.

```
$(document).on('click', '#project-table tr', function(){
    alert('This is a click on a dynamic element');
});
```

Here, we've bound the click event to the `document`. You can choose an element that is closer (for performance increases) if you so choose.

[Here is the link to the documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As a side note -- in jQuery 1.9 +, a few functions have been removed. One of them is the `.live()` function, which has been replaced with the `.on()` method (as displayed above). This is why it didn't work. Also, the `console` will tell you this. Many current browsers come with their own `web inspector`, otherwise you can do a google search for your browser and find an alternative.